# Query for converting rows in columns

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, pivot

I want to covert rows to columns.  IE: Take the following:

```
HOPPER_CLOSE_TIME     HOPPER_OPEN_TIME     SR_NO    CAL_DONE  PARTIAL_CALC_DONE_TIME
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
23-06-2011 10:26:41   23-06-2011 10:29:23  535100   2         23-06-2011 10:28:41
```

and i want it this way

```
HOPPER_CLOSE_TIME         23-06-2011 10:26:41
HOPPER_OPEN_TIME          23-06-2011 10:29:23
SR_NO                     535100
CAL_DONE                  2
PARTIAL_CALC_DONE_TIME    23-06-2011 10:28:41
```

Comment: why? that's just a frontend/display issue.

Comment: search SO for pivot and unpivot (possible before 11g, but built into 11g as new functions)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
select HOPPER_CLOSE_TIME  new_column_name from table1 where your_condition_here
union all
select  HOPPER_OPEN_TIME  new_column_name from table1 where your_condition_here
union all
select  SR_NO             new_column_name from table1 where your_condition_here
union all
select CAL_DONE           new_column_name from table1 where your_conidtion_here
union all
selectnPARTIAL_CALC_DONE_TIME new_column_name from table1 where your_condition_here
```

Comment: This won't work: you will have to do some datatype conversion as well.

Comment: union all requires that all corresponding columns have the same datatype. Even if you do the TO_CHAR conversion, it is not as efficient as selecting one row and doing the pivot on the client/UI.